# Custom window popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Besides `window.alert()`,`window.confirm()` and `window.prompt()`, is it possible to create custom popup decision?

For example: When you write a comment on facebook and try to close the window, a popup appears and its buttons are Leave and Stay.

Comment: These are native dialogs that are up to the browser to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out bootstrap modals

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

There are other css frameworks and libraries that implement modals as well. Essentially these are just divs that have a higher z-index than the rest of the page with some buttons on them. Because of this they are completely customizable.

Comment: So we need to create manually. I thought there might be window.custompop or something like this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah essentially. Browsers only give you so many options by default, all of which you seem to be aware of. If you do decide to use bootstraps modals, also check out bootbox. http://bootboxjs.com/ which makes dynamic modal creation easier.

If I've answered your question, please click the check mark near my answer to confirm. Thanks!